# object emptied in foreach loop

Tags: c#

I have a list being passed into a foreach loop which removes 0 or more items from the list.  Based on conditions it is possible for the list to be entirely emptied which causes a null reference error.  What is the best way to handle this sort of situation?

```
foreach (Item i in items)
{
    if (i.property == condition)
    {
        items.Remove(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot modify sequence which you are enumerating. How did you managed to entirely empty items list?

Comment: I can't think of any language I know that works properly when you try to remove elements from something you're iterating over. There are many ways to do this though, from `items.RemoveAll`,  to cloning the list, iterating over one and removing from the other, to storing the indices and removing the elements after the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [List.RemoveAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
items.RemoveAll(i => i.property == condition)
```

It removes all the elements that match the conditions defined by the specified
 predicate.

You also can leave original list (or another collection) untouched by creating new list without items which match condition (sometimes that might be useful)

```
var newItems = items.Where(i => i.property != condition).ToList();
```